# Does VSCode support impex files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, impex

Does VSCode support impex files?
Is there any extension, plugin or whatever in VSCode to support impex files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) to search for extensions.

Unfortunately it appears there are no extensions related to impex, hybris, or SAP.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [there is now](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=hybris&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) an extension for impex (added last few words as it would not let me submit otherwise - like imdb comments)